# Uno Wifi rev2 - SSL socket connection

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno-wifi

On Arduino Uno Wifi rev2 I want to create an SSL socket to my own SSL socket server implementation.

The board can download a webpage with encryption (after I've installed the certificate into it of course).

For my own SSL socket server implementation I'm using OpenSSL.

The board can connect to my own SSL socket server without any issues.

I want to enable [SSL_VERIFY_PEER](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) in my socket server.

With this option I can verify if peer is valid and true.

However after enabling this option, the Arduino is not able to connect to my socket anymore.

My question: **is peer certificate sending can be achieved on Ublox NINA W10x**?

Comment: What is the current code you're using?

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't know the answer. the firmware updater allows to upload certificates to nina firmware. the ESP32 IDF used to build the firmware has support for verifying a client certificate.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt the question is what code do I need to use to ask NINA to provide the client certificate upon request.

Comment: @Juraj: Can ESP32 IDF make a firmware for NINA W10x?

Comment: you have the firmware in the Uno WiFi Rev 2. only I don't know if the firmware and the library support client certificates

Comment: Yes I know that the firmware is in the Uno. (To be more exact it is in the NINA W10x). Do you know ESP32 IDF is able to create a firmware for the NINA W10x?

Comment: I don't understand. The arduino nina-fw project uses the IDF framework https://github.com/arduino/nina-fw